# Weird results obtained while solving a set of coupled differential equations (using a sparse array) in python

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I have tried to no avail for a week while trying to solve a system of coupled differential equations and reproduce the results shown in the attached image. I seem to be getting weird results as shown also. I don't seem to know what I might be doing wrong.The set of coupled differential equations were solved using Newman's BAND. Here's a link to the python implementation: [python solution using BAND](http://www.joshuagallaway.com/PyBand_Porous_Tafel_Gallaway_V1.txt) . And another link to the original image of the problem in case the attached is not clear enough: [here you find a clearer image of the problem](http://www.joshuagallaway.com/?p=946). Now what I am trying to do is to solve the same problem by creating a sparse array directly from the discretized equations using a combination of sympy and numpy and then solving using scipy's spsolve. Here is my code below. I need some help to figure out what I am doing wrong.[image: image of the problem, the correct soln and my soln here]
I have represented the variables as c1 = cA, c2 = cB, c3 = cC, c4 = cD in my code. Equation 2 has been linearized and phi10 and phi20 are the trial values of the variables cC and cD.

```
# import modules
import numpy as np
import sympy
from sympy.core.function import _mexpand
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse as ss
import scipy.sparse.linalg as ssl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define functions
def flatten(t):
    """
    function to flatten lists
    """
    return [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]


def get_coeffs(coeff_dict, func_vars):
    """
    function to extract coefficients from variables
    and form the sparse symbolic array
    """
    c = coeff_dict
    for i in list(c.keys()):
        b, _ = i.as_base_exp()
        if b == i:
            continue
        if b in c:
            c[i] = 0
        if any(k.has(b) for k in c):
            c[i] = 0

    return [coeff_dict[val] for val in func_vars]  

# Constants for the problem
I = 0.1                 # A/cm2
L = 1.0                 # distance (x) in cm
m = 100                 # grid spacing
h = L / (m-1)
a = 23300               # 1/cm
io = 2e-7               # A/cm2
n = 1
F = 96500               # C/mol
R = 8.314               # J/mol-K
T = 298                 # K
sigma = 20              # S/cm
kappa = 0.06            # S/cm
alpha = 0.5
beta = -(1-alpha)*n*F/R/T
phi10 , phi20 = 5, 0.5 # these are just guesses
P = a*io*np.exp(beta*(phi10-phi20))

j = sympy.symbols('j',integer = True)
cA = sympy.IndexedBase('cA')
cB = sympy.IndexedBase('cB')
cC = sympy.IndexedBase('cC')
cD = sympy.IndexedBase('cD')

# write the boundary conditions at x = 0
bc=[cA[1], cB[1],
(4/3)  * cC[2] - (1/3)*cC[3], # use a three point approximation for cC_prime
cD[1]
]

# form a list of expressions from the boundary conditions and equations
expr=flatten([bc,flatten([[
-cA[j-1] - cB[j-1] + cA[j+1] + cB[j+1],
cB[j-1] - 2*h*P*beta*cC[j] + 2*h*P*beta*cD[j] - cB[j+1],
-sigma*cC[j-1] + 2*h*cA[j] + sigma * cC[j+1],
-kappa * cD[j-1] + 2*h * cB[j] + kappa * cD[j+1]] for j in range(2, m)])])

vars = [cA[j], cB[j], cC[j], cD[j]]


# flatten the list of variables
unknowns = flatten([[cA[j], cB[j], cC[j], cD[j]] for j in range(1,m)])
var_len = len(unknowns)

# # # substitute in the boundary conditions at x = L while getting the coefficients
A = sympy.SparseMatrix([get_coeffs(_mexpand(i.subs({cA[m]:I}))\
    .as_coefficients_dict(), unknowns) for i in expr])




# convert to a numpy array
mat_temp = np.array(A).astype(np.float64)

# you can view the sparse array with this
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0, 1,1])
cmap = plt.cm.binary
plt.spy(mat_temp, cmap = cmap, alpha = 0.8)

def solve_sparse(b0, error):
    # create the b column vector
    b = np.copy(b0)
    b[0:4] = np.array([0.0, I, 0.0, 0.0])
    b[var_len-4] =   I
    b[var_len-3] =   0
    b[var_len-2] =   0
    b[var_len-1] =   0

    print(b.shape)
    
    old = np.copy(b0)

    mat = np.copy(mat_temp)
    b_2 = np.copy(b)
       
    resid = 10
    lss = 0
    while lss < 100:
        mat_2 = np.copy(mat)
  
        
        for j in range(3, var_len - 3, 4):

            # update the forcing term of equation 2
            b_2[j+2] = 2*h*(1-beta*old[j+3]+beta*old[j+4])*a*io*np.exp(beta*(old[j+3]-old[j+4]))
            
            # update the sparse array at every iteration for variables cC and cD in equation2
            mat_2[j+2, j+3] += 2*h*beta*a*io*np.exp(beta*(old[j+3]-old[j+4]))
            mat_2[j+2, j+4] += 2*h*beta*a*io*np.exp(beta*(old[j+3]-old[j+4]))
       
        # form the column sparse matrix 
        A_s = ss.csc_matrix(mat_2)
        new = ssl.spsolve(A_s, b_2).flatten()


        resid = np.sum((new - old)**2)/var_len
 
        lss += 1

        old = np.copy(new)
        
    return new


val0 = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] for _ in range(m-1)]).flatten() # form an array of initial values
error = 1e-7
## Run the code
conc = solve_sparse(val0, error).reshape(m-1, len(vars))


conc.shape  # gives (99, 4)
# Plot result for cA:
plt.plot(conc[:,0], marker = 'o', linestyle = '')
```

Comment: Is that really a calculation error, or is this a plotting error? It looks like you took the solution for the interval [100, 200] and shifted it back to the interval [0,100] in addition to the original solution there. Did you integrate and plot twice, the second time with the final values of the first integration as initial values?

Comment: Hi Lutz, I don't think it is a plotting error. I have updated the code to show the plot command. I did not plot twice. for example in the updated code the plot for conc[:,0] which is the first variable shows two lines.

Comment: Did you try to iterate out the numerical method? Do you get convergence at all? // With this kind of plot command you would need 4 of them to get 4 lines, this should be simple to debug.

Comment: As you can see in the code. I iterated in the solve sparse function. The residual was 1.591e-33 at 100 iterations. I would appreciate if you could try out the code and let me know where exactly the problem is coming from. I have tried to debug. But I know there is something not right in what I did and that's why I posted it. maybe some more trained eye could detect what I did wrong.

Comment: Yes, that was "reading too fast". Somehow I did associate the 100 with the discretization points, not the solver iteration. Not removing the line segments gives a visual confirmation that this is indeed only one plot. There has to be something wrong in the numerics.

Comment: exactly. There is something wrong in the numerics. I tried the same approach with a different set of coupled DEs and got the right answer but this particular problem is giving me a headache. PS: I am not expert at this. just trying my hands on this approach because it allows me enter the discretized equations the way they are using sympy.

Answer (score 0):

What happens seems pretty clear now, after having seen that the plotted solution indeed oscillates between the upper and lower values. You are using the *central Euler method* as discretization, for `u'=F(u)` this reads as

```
u[j+1]-u[j-1] = 2*h*F(u[j])
```

This method is only *weakly stable* and allows the sub-sequences of odd and even indices to evolve rather independently. As equation this would mean that the solution might approximate the system `ue'=F(uo), uo'=F(ue)` with independent functions `ue, uo` that follow the path of the even or odd sub-sequence.

These even and odd parts are only tied together by the treatment of the boundary points, two or three points deep. So to avoid or reduce the oscillation requires a very careful handling of boundary conditions and also the differential equations for the boundary points.

---

But one can avoid all this unpleasantness by using the *trapezoidal method*

```
u[j+1]-u[j] = 0.5*h*(F(u[j+1])+F(u[j]))
```

This also reduces the band-width of the system matrix.

---

To properly implement the implied *Newton method* correctly (linearizing via Taylor and solving the linearized equation is what the *Newton-Kantorovich method* does) you need to replace `F(u[j])` with `F(u_old[j])+F'(u_old[j])*(u[j]-u_old[j])`. This then gives a linear system of equations in `u` for the iteration step.

For the trapezoidal method this gives

```
(I-0.5*h*F'(u_old[j+1]))*u[j+1] - (I+0.5*h*F'(u_old[j]))*u[j] 

     = 0.5*h*(F(u_old[j+1])-F'(u_old[j+1])*u_old[j+1] + F(u_old[j])-F'(u_old[j])*u_old[j])
```

In general, the derivatives values and thus the system matrix need not be updated every step, only the function value (else the iteration does not move forward).

Comment: Hello Lutz, I'm afraid I don't understand completely. If you don't mind, could you update your solution with my code but having the correct discretization (like you stated). I think that would help me a lot.

Comment: You were right. did a little bit of further reading and found that the weird extra lines was because the central difference approximation contains no contribution from c[j] but rather, only from c[j-1] and c[j+1]. since information cannot be passed to adjacent points in the domain, two independent solutions arise. I used the forward difference instead(as advised) and the double solutions disappeared. now I have to struggle to find what else is not making me get the right solution

Comment: You could try to implement the Newton method correctly, that is, replace `F(u[j])` with `F(u_old[j])+F'(u_old[j])*(u[j]-u_old[j])` to get a linear equation in `u` for the iteration step. In general, the derivatives values and thus the system matrix need not be updated every step, only the function value (else the iteration does not move forward).